# Displaying multiple images from database in view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project where users should be able to upload images and have them shown on their individual page as a grid gallery.

I have watched this tutorial to be able to upload images from the application to the database and show an image with a specific ID. It all works fine.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5L5W-AE-sEs&

My view controller looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult View(int id)
        {
            Image imageModel = new Image();
            using (portfolio_project_dbEntities db = new portfolio_project_dbEntities())
            {
                imageModel = db.Images.Where(x => x.ImageID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            return View(imageModel);
        }
```

The view part:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" width="200"/>
```

Now I would like to be able to show multiple images on one page (images with the same userid) but I don't really understand how to do this. 
How do I pass multiple images from the controller to the view? Or maybe this is better to do in the view?

Comment: You may also want to consider creating a View Model for this that has a `public List<Image> Images {get; set; }` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FirstOrDefault` method returns a single item(or default) from a collection. So in the code you shared in the question where you are filtering the images using this expression `.Where(x => x.ImageID == id)` and then calling the `FirstOrDefault` method on that, which will yield a single item at max.

So If you want to show more than one item, remove that `FirstOrDefault` method call. In the below sample, I am assuming your `Image` object has a `UserId` property of `int` type and you want to filter the Image objects with `UserId` value same as your parameter value. So use an expression to check that in your `Where` method.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
   var images = new List<Image>();
   var db = new portfolio_project_dbEntities())
   {
      images  = db.Images
                  .Where(x => x.UserId == id)
                  .ToList();
    }
    // images is a list of Image objects. Let's pass it to the view.
    return View(images);
 }
```

Now since you are passing a  collection of `Image` objects to the view, make sure your view is strongly typed to a collection of `Image`.

```
@model IEnumerable<YourNamespaceHere.Image>
<h1>Images</h1>
@foeach(var img in Model)
{
  <img src="@Url.Content(img .ImagePath)" width="200"/>
}
```

Comment: This seems promising but I am having problem with my database. It is no longer shown in the Server explorer so I am trying to connect again but it doesn't seem to exist? It clearly does since the website still works and displays data from it though.. I would like to add the field UserID to my Image table. That is why I am trying to reach it.